# React and GraphQL on one server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, graphql

I am setting up a fullstack app with express & graphQL on the backend vs react on the frontend. I put the react app on a client folder on the backend repo. I direct all the urls except `api/graphql` to the client app, however I couldn't find a way to direct graphql requests to the server.

```
app.use(express.static('client/build'));

app.get('/api/graphql', (req, res) => {
  //What to do here to direct traffic to graphql server
});

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + 'client/build/index.html'));
});
```

and I am also creating the server with path and attaching `middleware` with its path so adding `graphqlHTTP` is not working.

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  context: async ({ req, res }) => {
    return context;
  },
});

await server.start();

server.applyMiddleware({
  cors: corsConfiguration,
  app,
  path: '/api/graphql',
});
```

any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

GraphQL has documentation on [combining it with Express](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/running-an-express-graphql-server/). They provide a simple code sample you should easily be able to adapt:

```js
var express = require('express');
var { graphqlHTTP } = require('express-graphql');
var { buildSchema } = require('graphql');
 
// Construct a schema, using GraphQL schema language
var schema = buildSchema(`
  type Query {
    hello: String
  }
`);
 
// The root provides a resolver function for each API endpoint
var root = {
  hello: () => {
    return 'Hello world!';
  },
};
 
var app = express();
app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
  schema: schema,
  rootValue: root,
  graphiql: true,
}));
app.listen(4000);
console.log('Running a GraphQL API server at http://localhost:4000/graphql');
```